# Using lists within lists in AppEngine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, arraylist, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to store arraylists within arraylists in the AppEngine datastore? I found this topic from 2010: [Datastore list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028355/datastore-list-of-lists) that recommends using pickle, but I'd like to use as few packages as possible.

Have there been any updates on AppEngine's datastore that would allow this?
Our arraylist inside arraylist has 5 or so layers, if that is important.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, nothing has been added that would specifically make this any easier. I think that my advice in the question that you cited still stands.

Comment: Alright, it's at least good to know what I have to do. Thanks.